# adding class active to submenu after reloading page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

After clicking the li item, i added the active class with js but it leads to the other page and the active class disappears. 
I am using bootstap [navwalker](https://gist.github.com/twittem/6358588) so don't know how to use php code into it.

```
<div id="cssmenu" class="right-tabs">

 <ul>
   <li></li>
   <li> 
     <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="link.php">link</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="page.php">page</a></li>
 </ul>  

</div>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$(".dropdown-menu > li").click(function () {
      $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

Comment: On the server side when generating menu you should mark the corresponding html element with active class according the requesting page.

Comment: @xxxmatko how am i to achieve that ?

Comment: Lets say the `li` element redirect user to page `something.php` so on the server side when you will render menu, if you are rendering menu item for the `something.php` you will add the class `active` to the current rendering `li` element. you can get the url on the server side in php, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just add the class based on the url?

**Example** assuming your on a about page

```
$(function() {
  var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
  if(/about/.test(loc)) {
    $('.dropdown-menu > li .about').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: Although it will set `active` every page that has the word about inside it's `href`

Comment: if the variable "loc" returns the full url, why do we have "/about/.test(loc)" in the if condition

Answer (score 0):

in link.php, add active class

```
<div id="cssmenu" class="right-tabs">

<ul>
<li></li>
<li class="activeClass"> 
  <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="link.php">link</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
  <li><a href="page.php">page</a></li>
</ul>
```